# Python NBA stats

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree

I am trying to print the player ID's and PPG for each player in the following XML http://api.cbssports.com/fantasy/stats?version=3.0&timeframe=2014&period=ytd&SPORT=basketball

However when I print nothing is printed and I don't know why:

```
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen, URLError
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

request = Request('http://api.cbssports.com/fantasy/stats?version=3.0&timeframe=2014&period=ytd&SPORT=basketball')

try:
    response = urlopen(request)
    tree = ET.parse(response)
    root = tree.getroot()
    for stats in root.findall('.//player_stats/stats'):
        id = stats.get('player_id')
        PPG = stats.get('stat abbr="PPG"')
        print id, PPG
except URLError, e:
    print 'error:', e
```

Comment: Reading the docs and looking at the response should be really enough to figure that out... - https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stats` is not a direct child of `player_stats`.

Instead, iterate over `player` nodes, get the `id` from `attrib` dictionary. In order to ding `PPG` value, use `findtext()`:

```
for stats in root.findall('.//player_stats/player'):
    id = stats.attrib.get('id')
    PPG = stats.findtext('.//stat[@abbr="PPG"]')
    print id, PPG
```

Prints:

```
1992786 24.6
307818 12.2615384615385
555968 12.375
...
```